# linear algebra - A single solution, an infinite number of solutions, and there is no solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I can not find what k values There is a single solution, infinite solutions, there is no solution.

orginal matrix:

[image: orginal matrix]

After ranking:

[image: After ranking]

-k^2+k+10 >> When I want to get a single solution I compare the expression zero but the quadratic equation answers outgoing incomplete. How do I reset the expression? To get infinite solutions and there is no solution to what should I do?

thank you.

Comment: This matrix is extended. There are three variables x,y,z.

Comment: -k2+k+10 /= 0 to single solution? but i get 3.7 and -2.7 When I solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: So my matrix ranking is not true?

Comment: I do not know how to get there >>>10(k2−k−2)=10(k−2)(k+1)

Comment: Is this an augmented matrix? If not, where are the RHS of the equations? Is the field real or complex? Please complete the question.